# For the field $F=\{a+b\sqrt{3}\}$, find $d$ so that $b\cdot d=1$, where $b,d\in F$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, field-theory

For the field $F=\{a+b\sqrt{3}\}$, find $d$ so that $b\cdot d=1$, where $b,d\in F$

Let $b=a_1+b_1\sqrt{3}$

Let $d=a_2+b_2\sqrt{3}$

We need to find $a_2,b_2$ such that $b\cdot d=1$

Doing the math, we get that $b\cdot d=(a_1a_2+3b_1b_2)+(a_1b_2+a_2b_1)\sqrt{3}$

But what from here? How do I decide that I want $(a_1a_2+3b_1b_2)$ to equal $0$, and so I want $(a_1b_2+a_2b_1)$ to be $1$. Or I want the first part of the expression to be $1$, and the next part to be $0$. How do I decide?

Comment: Your $b\cdot d$ seems to lack some $\sqrt 3$. Correcting this should facilitate your decision

Comment: Also, just for fun multiply $b$ with its conjugate $a_1-b_2\sqrt 3$ and see if you can find suitable $d$ from that result.

Comment: What are $a,b$? You haven't quite specifed $F$ unless you tell us where $a,b$ come from. Hint: $(a_1+b_1\sqrt3)(a_1-b_1\sqrt3)$ is an element of the same field $a_1,b_1$ are from.

Comment: Okay sorry I added in the $\sqrt{3}$, but still, how will I know what to make $0$ and what to make $1$

Comment: @fleablood yes but i realise that i didnt quite understand how we chose the first equation to be set to $0$ and the other one to $1$

Comment: Then you should have asked *there*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like in you *other* exact same question that *YOU* posted [Show that the set $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p})=\{a+b\sqrt{p}; a,b,p\in\mathbb{Q},\sqrt{p}\notin \mathbb{Q}\}$ is a field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2420797/show-that-the-set-mathbbq-sqrtp-ab-sqrtp-a-b-p-in-mathbbq-sqrt/2421097#2421097)

You note that if $\gamma \in \mathbb Q \subset \mathbb Q[\sqrt{3}]$ and $\gamma$ is of the form $a + b \sqrt{3}; a,b$ then $b = 0$.

====

Note the "definition" $F= \{a + b\sqrt{3}\}$ isn't very well defined unless you specify what values $a,b$ might be.  I am assuming you are trying to say $F = \mathbb Q[\sqrt{3}]$; a field extension of $\mathbb Q$.  As $(\sqrt 3)^2 = 3 \in \mathbb Q$ we can conclude that or any $n \in \mathbb Z$ that $(\sqrt{3})^n= c+d\sqrt{3}$ for some $c,d \in \mathbb Q$ and that $ \mathbb Q[\sqrt{3}] $ which is consists of all linear combinations of rationals and the powers of $\sqrt{3}$ is $\{a+b\sqrt{3}|a,b \in \mathbb Q\}$.

(Thanks to Lykri Lahtonen, for not letting this slide in the comments.  I was going to let it pass, even though I shouldn't.)

====

You note that because the $\sqrt{3}$ is irrational, and $a_1, b_1,a_2,b_2$ are all rational that $b\cdot d=(a_1a_2+3b_1b_2)+(a_1b_2+a_2b_1)\sqrt{3}=1$ means that

$(a_1b_2+a_2b_1)\sqrt{3} = 1 - (a_1a_2+3b_1b_2)$.

If $a_1b_2+a_2b_1 \ne 0$ then

$\sqrt 3 = \frac {1 - (a_1a_2+3b_1b_2)}{a_1b_2+a_2b_1}\in \mathbb Q$.

This is impossible so $a_1b_2+a_2b_1 = 0$.

So $a_1b_2+a_2b_1 = 0$  and $a_1a_2+3b_1b_2=1$.

So solve those.

=====

One thing you should realize and should be intuively obvious is if you have

a field $F$ and you extend it with $\omega \not \in F$

$\gamma \in F[\omega]$ so that $\gamma = a + b\omega; a,b \in F$

And you find that $\gamma = c \in F$ then it has to be that $\gamma \in F$ and so for $\gamma = a + b\omega$ that $b = 0$.

======

So $(a_1a_2 + 3b_1b_2) + (a_1b_2+a_2b_1)\sqrt 3 = 1 \in \mathbb Q$.

The only elements $a+b\sqrt{3} \in \mathbb Q$ are of the form $a + 0*\sqrt{3}$.

So $a_1a_2+3b_2b_2 =1$ and $a_1b_2 + a_2b_2 = 0$.